# mySQLdump from Linux machine to a mounted Windows folder on a remote server

Tags: linux, windows, mount

I am trying to do a mysqldump from a local Linux machine to a Windows folder that has been mounted on the system.  This is the command I am using in the terminal:

```
mysqldump -u root -plinuxsux myDB -t LOG > /mounted folder/path/blah/myDB.sql
```

I am getting the following error:

```
/mounted folder/path/blah/myDB.sql: Permission denied
```

I checked the permissions of the folder on the Windows side, and there is a specific user that I created called Sys003 that has full control of that folder.

Do I need to put that user name (and password) into the command above to get it to work?  And if so, how do I do that?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the user that is actually running the `mysqldump` command has not the permission to write on the destination folder.

One solution might be changing to the `Sys003` user and run the `mysqldump` again:

```
normal_prompt> su Sys003
password...
Sys003_prompt> mysqldump...
```

Another one can be running `mysqldump` as your normal user, then copy the dump as `Sys003`:

```
normal_prompt> mysqldump... > /local/dump.sql
normal_prompt> su Sys003
password...
Sys003_prompt> cp /local/dump.sql /mounted_folder/path/blah/myDB.sql
```

Be careful, since your `Sys003` user might not be authorized on running `mysqldump`, but that's a totally different question :)

Comment: Thanks, I found the problem though.

Answer (score 0):

It was an error in the /etc/fstab file.  I had the user as a different user than Sys003.  Once I put the user as Sys003 with their password, it worked.